# Edit Sublime Text 2's default snippets

Tags: editor, code-snippets, sublimetext

I've been using Sublime text 2 for the past few days, and I have to say it's been amazing!

I have added many snippets already, but can't figure out how to edit Sublime's default snippets like the script element (<kbd>script</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>).

In my opinion the script element shouldn't have a type attribute in HTML5, so I'd like to edit that snippet.

Problem is, I can't find it in the `/Packages/User` folder like the user defined snippets.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For this its in `Packages/HTML/HTML.sublime-completions`. To find this kind of stuff all you have to do is do a `find anything` (Ctrl+Shift+F on linux, don't know for mac..) then bung the sublime folder in the `where` field and search away!

Comment: To avoid your changes being over-written by Sublime or package updates, copy the file to your Packages/User folder first, and edit that rather than the original.

Comment: @JeremyHalliwell - I tried doing that - but Sublime seems to still use the original default snippet?

Comment: On a Mac, the full path to the Packages folder is `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`

Comment: The packages folder doesn't exist on Sublime Text 3. Do you know how to change this in ST3?

Comment: Sorry, never its there, but it doesn't have the default packages

Answer (score 17):

**Mac Answer**
Go in the menu: 
**Sublime Text 2** -> **Preferences** -> **Browse Packages...**
Than open the **HTML** folder.
Double click on **html_completions.py**
Search for script and edit the value.
Hope this help someone.

Comment: I've been looking for this for a long time, thank you

Comment: wanted to delete a snippet I created, but couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks